# Backbone.js slash after hash in fallback - history pushState

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm using [Backbone.js's routing](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router).
It generate urls for browsers like this:

```
http://my-app.com/help
```

For Internet Explorers (except IE10) and old non-HTML5 browsers:

```
http://my-app.com/#help
```

**How to configure Backbone.js to generate fallback urls with additional slash, like this?:**

```
http://my-app.com/#/help
```

Comment: I cheked the [source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-96) and I was not able to figure out a way without changes in backbone.js itself. But maybe I'm just blind :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe that your 2nd code block is entirely different than the 3rd. The preceding slash is set on the property name.

```
routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  }
```

is different than:

```
routes: {
    "/help":                 "help",    // #/help
    "/search/:query":        "search",  // #/search/kiwis
    "/search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #/search/kiwis/p7
  }
```

Comment: OK, for IE urls look good `http://my-app.com/#/help` However for standard browser two slashes `http://my-app.com//help`

Comment: It's likely that backbone only handles it one way. Though, the backbone docs do note that you can bind routes based on a regular expression `this.route(/^(\/)?help$/, "help", function(){ ... });` This will recognize the route with or without the prefixed slash.

Comment: They document it by manually binding it. Test it out in the route definition as well.

Comment: On another note, the newest version of Backbone (0.9.1) does not allow prefixing with a slash.  Apparently it's not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit old, but since the accepted answer no longer works in newer versions of Backbone, I figured I would share my findings.

I found a way to get this to work in IE8 and Chrome (have not testing any other browsers) - if you are using Backbone.history for navigation.

If you use two preceding slashes in the navigate call, it will create the Url like you want it.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('//help');
```

I did not change the routes at all - they do not start with a slash. Putting a slash there seemed to break it.

I should also note that I am using Marionette with Backbone as perhaps that could make a difference.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I was trying this and it updated the url correctly to show `/#/` (prettier), but now that triggers the route :/ Looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly hack to get around it: override [getHash()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-125). Here's the original code:

```
getHash: function(windowOverride) {
  var loc = windowOverride ? windowOverride.location : window.location;
  var match = loc.href.match(/#(.*)$/);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
},
```

It seems to work after adding an extra slash to the regexp:

```
Backbone.History.prototype.getHash = function(windowOverride) {
  var loc = windowOverride ? windowOverride.location : window.location;
  var match = loc.href.match(/#\/(.*)$/);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
}
```

Navigate might not work after this, but it could probably be fixed with a similar hack.