# URL fragments: a leading slash in your hash url - good or bad?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, trailing-slash

Just need to know whether it is a good or not to have **a leading slash in your hash url**. For instance,

```
site.come/#/directore/file/
```

or

```
site.come/#directore/file/
```

I am asking this because backbone.js does not recommend the first option in their docs (personally I prefer the first option...),

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend

> Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route
>   definitions

So I want to make sure what the reasons are behind this that you `want to avoid using a leading slash`.

Comment: I believe the main reason is it can cause future incompatibilities with the history api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both methods are bad if the website should be public, as it would hurt SEO.

Conisder using `#!` as google [instructs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq#whentousewhich) people to do so that the website is crawlable

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that I can think of ([referencing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529836/are-double-forward-slashes-ok-in-url-hash-fragment?rq=1#answer-11260462)) is incompatibilities if you decide to use `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`

Consider this setup:

```
Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "/test": "test"
    "test": "test2"
  }
});
```

The `history` api is still not set in stone so how it treats and calls routes with slashes is inconsistent - but you should expect `history.pushState('/test')` to call route `test`. However, now if you're on a browser that is using the hash fallback it will call route `/test/`. Therefore, its probably better to avoid the first slash altogether as there is no good way of telling where this will take you without handling both cases:

```
app.navigate("/test")
```

Also this is a possible duplicate of [Backbone.js slash after hash in fallback - history pushState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461346)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the first one as this keep the URL more clean. Even AngularJS routing system prefers the first one. like:

```
site.com/#/directory/file
```

for SEO purpose, both doesn't have any meaning at all.
Yes, thats right, hitory API uses `#!` in their URL formation system.